# How to cancel a particular user's(end users) subscription via razorpay api

Tags: razorpay

I am using the razorpay API. In my web application I want to implement a functionality through which an user can stop their recurring payment.

I have only found an option for cancelling the entire subscription by the API owner. I have checked the razorpay api documentation as well.

Is it possible to implement this requirement via razorpay API?

Answer (score 0):

A unique subscription_id gets generated against each user. So, you can cancel the same using this API: https://razorpay.com/docs/subscriptions/api/subscriptions/#cancel-a-subscription